# IE9 Developer Tools - Remote Diagnostics

Tags: internet-explorer-9, developer-tools

I need to be able to diagnose client-side code issues using IE9 (F12) developer tools (its the only piece of software I can assume customers have).

I've been trying to find out where AJAX calls are detailed, along with their response (like Firebug does) but can't find anything.

Can I do this using IE9 developer tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. Take a look at the [following article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg130952%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).